# How can I know if the 2 exe have different code?

Tags: c, checksum

I have a working exe for a particular program which was built a month ago. I accidentally deleted the exe in the development environment so I compiled a new exe. However, I have a copy of the working exe in uat environment and its checksum is different from the new exe.

The 2 exe have same size:

> ----------+ 1 raymond1 Domain Users   623616 Jan  3 16:47 A.EXE;24
>
> ----------+ 1 raymond1 Domain Users   623616 Jan  4 11:11 A.EXE;25

But they got different checksums:

```
$ sha1sum "A.EXE;24"
cb87ec4b746677903969ba61361a60c14461b5e0 *RIIB.EXE;24
$ sha1sum "A.EXE;25"
09453f40e53e280abbb98bd0013f1ddf312706b8 *RIIB.EXE;25
```

So I wonder if there is any problem with the way I generated the new exe maybe I forget to compile some program it depends on.

Anyway, I compiled another exe with the exact same way I did for version 25. It still got the same size with the other two exe. I just linked it again. But version 26 got different checksum too.

```
$ sha1sum "RIIB.EXE;26"
e2378544a91db49927738fd0135181b9daf125be *RIIB.EXE;26
```

So I wonder if I could find out what is the different between them.

P.S. The exe was generated in OpenVms, I ftp it to my machine for the checksum ( CYGWIN in WIN 7 ).

EDIT:

I followed the advices in the comments and do a binary diff.

here is the result:

```
$ xxd "A.EXE;24" > b24.hex
$ xxd "A.EXE;25" > b25.hex
$ xxd "A.EXE;26" > b26.hex

$ diff b24.hex b25.hex
34849,34850c34849,34850
< 0088200: 1900 0060 0000 0000 6ff8 42de 9b2c 0100  ...`....o.B..,..
< 0088210: 3500 0060 0000 0000 8c6f f842 de9b ac00  5..`.....o.B....
---
> 0088200: 1900 0060 0000 0000 62b3 87f4 cd2c 0100  ...`....b....,..
> 0088210: 3500 0060 0000 0000 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  5..`.....b......
38862c38862
< 0097cd0: 4950 462f 564d 5300 8c6f f842 de9b ac00  IPF/VMS..o.B....
---
> 0097cd0: 4950 462f 564d 5300 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  IPF/VMS..b......
38868c38868
< 0097d30: 0100 0000 0300 0000 8c6f f842 de9b ac00  .........o.B....
---
> 0097d30: 0100 0000 0300 0000 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  .........b......
38872c38872
< 0097d70: 4950 462f 564d 5300 8c6f f842 de9b ac00  IPF/VMS..o.B....
---
> 0097d70: 4950 462f 564d 5300 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  IPF/VMS..b......    

$ diff b25.hex b26.hex
34849,34850c34849,34850
< 0088200: 1900 0060 0000 0000 62b3 87f4 cd2c 0100  ...`....b....,..
< 0088210: 3500 0060 0000 0000 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  5..`.....b......
---
> 0088200: 1900 0060 0000 0000 10a5 1c14 ce2c 0100  ...`.........,..
> 0088210: 3500 0060 0000 0000 e710 a51c 14ce ac00  5..`............
38862c38862
< 0097cd0: 4950 462f 564d 5300 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  IPF/VMS..b......
---
> 0097cd0: 4950 462f 564d 5300 e710 a51c 14ce ac00  IPF/VMS.........
38868c38868
< 0097d30: 0100 0000 0300 0000 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  .........b......
---
> 0097d30: 0100 0000 0300 0000 e710 a51c 14ce ac00  ................
38872c38872
< 0097d70: 4950 462f 564d 5300 0b62 b387 f4cd ac00  IPF/VMS..b......
---
> 0097d70: 4950 462f 564d 5300 e710 a51c 14ce ac00  IPF/VMS.........
```

They have the different in the same line. Maybe it is the timestamp causing problem?

Comment: At a minimum, the build timestamps will be different in the PE headers.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Would that mean that their size is different?

Comment: @H2CO3 There are two different cases: 1) You can compile the same source twice, and (due to the build timestamps) end up with binaries with different SHA1 hashes. 2) You can compile different source, and (due to file/section alignment) end up with binaries with the same size.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ah, I got it. You can't produce two identical executables even from the same codebase.

Comment: You could do a binary diff between v25 and v26 & see which bytes cause the hash change.  Since you know the only difference is the time of compilation: http://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux .  If it's only the same bytes that differ with v24 you know it's just the timestamp that's changing the hash.

Comment: It also happens, that eg. `__LINE__` values can change inbetween two distributions ending into _different but same_ binaries. First you could `od -t x1 binX.exe >binX.txt; od -t x1 binY.exe >binY.txt; diff binX.txt binY.txt` to check the magnitude of the difference.

Comment: `sha1sum "file" will be different even if you change single bit two `.exe`.  May be compiler insert something even if you have not changed files. **Mitch Wheat** Is correct its can't be answer 100%. But upto some extend its possible using disassemble.

Comment: The code was not changed. What happened was that I deleted some obj files from the system ( thinking I don't need them once I got a working exe ). Anyway I generated the obj files again for the compilation.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 I guess the real question is, what do you care? `make clean` and be done with it. Your code is checked into a versioning system, *right*? Well then, any build from the same revision will be *functionally* identical. Don't worry about the SHA1.

Comment: It looks to me like it's the same byte locations that change between v24/v25 and v25/v26, so yes I'd say it's a reasonable assumption that that they're the same code.

Comment: `diff <(xxd file1.bin) <(xxd file2.bin)` :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Why I care is that I had messed with the obj files. Although it is quite complex, I guess I got the right obj files generated. Anyway I am not sure about it because I can't check it easily by executing the 2 exe.

Comment: Why would someone vote a clear and real question to be closed as "not a real question"?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the program functionality is concerned, there is no difference between the 2 versions given you compiled exactly the same code with exactly the same parameters (unless you have some extremely weird compiler bug). Note, you may also have some dependency on environmental settings in your code, such as date or time compiler-generated constants - which naturally can be different for each compilation.

The signature is and should be different because there are additional factors that affect the actual generated binary, such as time of compilation, environment, compiler meta-data or state of the weather during compilation. In fact, if the signature was the same, that would mean that `sha1` is worthless.

**Edit:**

Compiler-generated constants such as `__LINE__` (e.g., a pre-build script might inject some `#define`s into code for code-analysis tools), `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` may change from one compilation to another.

The compiler may choose not to recompile some files if it considers the `.obj` to be up to date (and that's not always correct, especially if precompiled headers are used, but not only - resulting in invalid .exe). Moreover, the linker may have internal considerations regarding the order of linkage due to speed or optimization or any other reason.

Comment: -1 Sorry, there is just a bit too much nonsense in this. I think if you zero out the timestamp and checksum from the PE headers, I can't think of any reason the SHA1 hashes couldn't be the same. The state of the weather (yes, I know it was a pun), or any other pseudo-random factors don't enter into it. "environment, compiler meta-data" also don't really make sense.

Comment: If a file.o is missing, there's a chance of completely different implementation of a function taking place without changing linked file-size. (dynamic linking)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen explain? First of all, these are `.exe`s, there won't be any `.o` files. If you meant `.obj` files, you're also incorrect, because those will be statically linked into the executable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart oh, really? Dependency on `__LINE__` (as was mentioned in the comments) or `__TIME__` will result in different code.  Different order of linkage may result in different executable layout (and the OP mentioned deleting some `.obj` files) - haven't you ever encountered the need to rebuild the entire project? That's the reason

Comment: @icepack Why would compiling "exactly the same code" change `__LINE__`?  Yes, `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` would change the output, but I would think that would be pretty obvious to anyone asking this question. I would agree with the linkage order argument, if I could come up with any reason why the linker would ever use a different order of .obj files that are in theory, almost identical (remember, same code).

Comment: In cygwin there are both '.exe' and '.o' -files. (don't know about openVMS)

Comment: Perhaps the downvote was harsh. It requires some edit for me to remove it, however.